# What will happen if tomcat has two war (root.war, login.war) and my root.war has path /login?

Tags: java, tomcat, war

I have two war file that needs to be deployed in tomcat. One is root.war(path will be / as per tomcat docs) and login.war(path will be /login). My root.war has also a path named /login. For some reason my deployment crashed. I would like to know, does it happening becuase of conflict or Am I missing something ? How does tomcat url path working. Any resource will be helpful.

Comment: have you read the logs created by the deployment?

Comment: as far as I remember, the servlet spec covers the precedence, but I currently have no time to hunt it down. My expectation (but that's just gut feeling) is that the root webapp will only be the fallback once the more specific apps have been searched for a match. But that might be completely wrong - the specification is the authoritative source on that. As for the deployment-failure reason, I second the question for the logs - they typically are quite informative